# Installing PCNTL module for PHP without recompiling

Tags: php, centos

Is it possible to install the [pcntl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) module without recompiling php? I'm trying to set this up on CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to find module with yum command
yum search pcntl

Answer (score 9):

I haven't been able to get it working purely through a package manager, and `yum search pcntl` finds no matches, even after setting up some additional repositories.

I ended up finding one way that worked without reinstalling PHP entirely, though it does end up requiring a *tiny* bit of recompilation.  A post found [here](https://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/viewtopic.php?topic_id=8557) mentions a somewhat straightforward way of compiling and enabling just the pcntl extension ( with a little editing and reformatting of the post):

```
Get your current php version (check phpinfo())
Get the sources for that version here: http://www.php.net/releases/
Extract this file; you will got folder name like php5-x.x.x
Run following lines in terminal:

cd php5-x.x.x/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php/modules/
echo "extension=pcntl.so" > /etc/php.d/pcntl.ini
restart apache

Note: if your /usr/lib/php/modules/ or /etc/php.d/ is not same
as this, you could try 'locate php/modules' or 'locate php.d'
```

Comment: This was *extremely* help to me and worked!  Thank you very much.

Comment: When running configure `configure: error: Cannot find php-config. Please use --with-php-config=PATH`

Comment: After adding the ondrej ppa and installing `php8.0-dev` error is gone

Answer (score 6):

The pcntl module is in the `php-cli` package and can be installed with yum by using the following command:

```
sudo yum install php php-cli
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if this extension enabled.

```
php -m
```

or

```
php-fpm -m
```

If not exist, so you should it enable during build or build it as extension.

Answer (score 0):

Download your existing PHP version repository from http://www.php.net/releases/ (This is no matter where you have to download & extract. You can either download to local machine. Just want to copy ext/pcntl to somewhere in the server)

Extract downloaded folder (Example: /home/downloads/PHP_5.x.x/)

```
cd /home/downloads/PHP_5.x.x/ext/pcntl
phpize
./configure
make
cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/
```

[*This path is depend on your PHP installation/configurations. You can check the PHP extension path in php.ini or echo phpinfo(); ]

```
echo "extension=pcntl.so" > /usr/local/lib/php.ini
```

or
Add the line "extension=pcntl.so" to your php.ini

```
vim /usr/lib/php.ini
```

[*again depend on your PHP installation. You can find the php.ini path in locate php.ini or  echo phpinfo(); ]